# Detail of list without user authentication

Tags: foursquare

I'm trying to get details of Foursquare list by [PHP library](https://github.com/stephenyoung/php-foursquare):

```
$foursquare = new FoursquareAPI($key,$secret);
$list = $foursquare->GetPublic('lists/'.$listId);
```

But everytime gets this error:

```
string(7672) "{"meta":{"code":200,"errorType":"deprecated","errorDetail":"Please provide an API version to avoid future errors.See https:\/\/developer.foursquare.co ... "
```

When I debug it, library calls this URL: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/lists/ with these params: `Array ( [client_id] => <client_id> [client_secret] => <client_secret> )`

But when I try this API method in [Foursquare API Explorer](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=lists/4e496b91d164a7c8b699f682) I see that, this URL is calling: `OAuth token automatically added. https://api.foursquare.com/v2/lists/<list_id>?oauth_token=<token>&v=20111205`.

In [lists doc](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/lists/lists.html) is *Requires Acting User: No*, so I'm confused. Is it possible to call this function without authenticating user?

It would be nice, because I want to add places from my list (favourite restaurants) to my page on Google map in Contacts. It would be useful for our clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is unrelated to the list endpoint you are requesting or the state of authentication. It is a warning that the library you are using is currently not following versioning best practice for Foursquare. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning).

As for the list there should be a `response` object at the same level as the `meta` object.

Comment: Thank you for your replay!

It's weird that recommended library by Foursquare don't reflect "v" param.

So I created simple CURL call, which works fine:)

Thanks:)